# Що означає слово "кумпель"?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники

У Львові є заклад із назвою "Кумпель". Зацікавило, що ж означає насправді це слово. Звернулась у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/kumpelj), однак саме такого слова там немає.

То **яка** ж **семантика слова "кумпель"**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значення цього слова знаходимо у [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C):

> • **Кумпель** — старольвівське слово, котре означає «товариш», «колєга»[1] Слово використовували львівські батяри.
>   • **«Кумпель»** — два ресторани регіональної кухні у центрі Львова. Ресторан-пивоварня «Кумпель», відкритий у 2008 році за адресою м. Львів, вул. Винниченка, 6.

У [Словарі українського сленгу](http://slovopedia.org.ua/57/53402/374919.html) знаходимо таке ж значення:

> **КУМПЕЛЬ** 
>   (-пля) ч.; мол. Товариш. Банзаїв кращий кумпель - Сергій Мокша, який усім представлявся як Дощ, - знайшов безтямного Юрка у квартирі на кухні (Л. Дереш, Культ). 
>   ■ Від польськ. розм. **kumpel** - приятель.

Отже, очевидно, власники цих ресторанів взяли за основу назви закладів львівське сленгове слово, яке запозичене з польської і значає **друг, приятель**.